# Java Adding multiple elements to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Still new to java, but I'm having an issue adding multiple new elements to my arraylist. 
The idea for this method is to look and see if a name is already in the list, and if so return false, and if not then add the name and person's score to the arraylist.
I keep getting an error when I try to add it in. The add will work if it's just the name portion I add in, but once I also include the scoreOn1st it gives me an error.

```
public boolean addGolfer(String name, int scoreOn1st)
{  
    // check if the golfer is already in the collection
    for (int i = 0; i < board.size(); i++)
    {
        if (board.get(i).equals(name))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // otherwise

    board.add(new ScoreCard(name, scoreOn1st));
    return true;
}
```

This is the constructor class already created for the arraylist:

```
public ScoreBoard(String tourneyName)
{    
    // initialize instance varable
    this.tournament = tourneyName;
    ArrayList<ScoreCard> board = new ArrayList<ScoreCard>();
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you use a Map instead of a List for this.

Comment: Generally it's a good idea to include what error you're getting. Many times it isn't inherently obvious.

Comment: what does your ScoreCard class look like? looks like your constructor does not expect an int parameter, and is its equal() function overloaded for string? I second BevynQ that a [Map](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/map.html) would probably more suitable

Comment: there error I get is: constructor ScoreCard in class ScoreCard cannot be applied to given types: required:java.lang.String; found java.lang.String, int;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The board should be declared outside. You can new it inside the constructor. The get !method returns a ScoreCard object on which you cannot directly call equals name.

```
public class ScoreBoard {
List<ScoreCard> board;
public ScoreBoard(String tourneyName)
{    
    this.tournament = tourneyName;
    this.board = new ArrayList<ScoreCard>(); 
}
```

ScoreCard should be something like this:

```
class ScoreCard {
  ScoreCard(String name) {//definition } //1st Constructor
  ScoreCard(String name, int score) { //definition } //2nd Constructor
```

Comment: Which part can you provide some details on what exact error you get

Comment: Also does scorecard have a proper constructor for both the fields.

Comment: The error I get is: constructor ScoreCard in class ScoreCard cannot be applied to given types: required:java.lang.String; found java.lang.String, int;

Comment: This says you just have a constructor for string (I guess name only) put in another constructor with name and score.

Comment: I get what you're saying, to edit the ScoreCard, but I'm not supposed to change that aspect of the code. I'm thinking maybe there is some way to make is all a string in it's own little array and then add it in? Or something like that.

Comment: You can append the score to the name in the array I guess. Or you can use a map with scorecard as the key and score as the value.

Comment: But looking at the problem score card should be having a score field with the name (u might have different requirement)

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor the board variable is a method variable not a field.

```
public ScoreBoard(String tourneyName)
{    
    // initialize instance varable
    this.tournament = tourneyName;
    this.board = new ArrayList<ScoreCard>(); // I assume you have declared this field.
}
```